# How to prevent blurry scrollbar on Windows Chrome after transform scale?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transforms

I'm facing a weird issue while trying to scale an HTML element. [As demonstrated in this codepen](https://codepen.io/codeheroics/pen/NWGVLYZ), I want the element to appear scaled down (`transform: scale(0.1)`), then animate itself and scale up to its full size (`transform: scale(1)`). The element is a big list limited in height using `overflow: auto;`, which means a scrollbar is displayed.

My issue is that the scrollbar arrows are not scaled up correctly compared to the rest of the elements, which makes them extremely blurry and unrecognizable to the user. This only seems to happen on Windows (10) when using Chrome. cf screenshot below

[image: Blurry scrollbar]

I haven't been able to find any one on the Web talking about this issue, and it seems a bit confounding to me as it doesn't seem to be an edge case, and it is pretty simple to reproduce.

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Comment: W10 Firefox does the scaling, but both Chrome and Edge (use the same code base since Edge March 2020) only show the thumb and hide the arrows until the animation 'settles'. Will be due to browser internal CSS, so I predict a lot of work ahead to get this in proper working order as you need to dive into browser developement and check per browser how to circumvent the behaviour. Would that be worth your time and effort?

Comment: Actually slowing down the transition does not help at all (even putting it at something like 15 seconds), you just get more time to see how blurry the arrows are

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment into a proper answer:

Slowing down the animation, you can see that the graphics engine of W10 Chrome and Edge (use the same code base since Edge March 2020) simply skip certain scrollbar 'paints' during the animation and only show the thumb whilst scaling...

W10 Firefox does the scaling as expected, however.

This is browser internal code, so I predict a lot of work ahead to circumvent the problem as you need to dive into browser developement and check per browser (HTML/CSS) how to avoid the behaviour.

Would that be worth your time and effort?

Comment: Slowing down the animation does not work, even much slower the problem keeps happening.

About the investment, diving into the internals of browser code is too much effort for this, but as it seems like an easy-to-reproduce bug I will file a bug report to the browsers.

I'm still hoping for a solution to this that would let me avoid this issue entirely, right now I'm thinking of hiding the scrollbars while the animation is ongoing as a workaround.

Comment: @Hugo Yep, ran the animation again on Chrome and Edge: no blur, but also no arrows. Will adjust my answer. About reporting, I expect this will not get high priority.

Answer (score 0):

A little change in your code seems to solve the issue.

Change scale by a perspective +  translateZ. this scales down the element (as it is now "far away"), and seems to not have the bug:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const className = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].className
document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].className = className ? '' : "shazam"
}, 2000)
```

```css
main {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: perspective(100px) translateZ(-1000px);
  transition: transform 1500ms;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.shazam {
  transform: perspective(100px) translateZ(0px);
}
```

```html
  <h1>List of interesting things I've done during lockdown</h1>
<main>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>… Who cares about lists anyway?</li>
  </ul>
</main>
```